# How to catch multiple rows in lex

Tags: c++, regex, lex

I want to make a regex for multiple rows sample.
I tried like this:

```
^"SAMPLE_SIGN"."\n".SAMPLE_SIGN\n    std::cout << "MULTIPLE ROW SAMPLE"
```

but this isn't working for me.

A possible input:

```
some program code SAMPLE_SIGN text inside the 
sample SAMPLE_SIGN
```

What is the correct version for this?

Comment: include some example input with expected output.

Comment: @Matt.G I updated my question

Comment: and what is the expected output?

Comment: @Matt.G I want to detect the SAMPLE_SIGN as a multiline comment for example or as a block begin and end sign, where the first `SAMPLE_SIGN` is the beginner, and the second is the ending one. I want to print the content from inside this two one now.

Comment: You are only allowing one character after `"SAMPLE_SIGN"` and again after the newline. You need `.*``.

Comment: @user207421 I tried like you said: `"SAMPLE_SIGN".*"\n".*SAMPLE_SIGN\n` but is not working for me. Did you thought otherwise than I used it?

Comment: Your input doesn't have `SAMPLE_SIGN` at the beginning of the line. If you want to allow it anywhere on a line, you shouldn't anchor it with `^`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to allow it in any position of the row, not only the begining then shouldn't use `^` and allow your sign: `SAMPLE_SIGN` or:`|` end of line:`\n` and after this can be anything `*`

```
"SAMPLE_SIGN"([^SAMPLE_SIGN]|\n)*"SAMPLE_SIGN"  std::cout << "Block"
```

This will allow you to use `SAMPLE_SIGN` as first character inside a block of `SAMPLE_SIGN` and. As a primitive comment section for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try Regex: `SAMPLE_SIGN([\S\s]+)(?=SAMPLE_SIGN)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4eNZr/1)

C++ Code [Demo](https://ideone.com/p6ipAm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
std::string txt("some program code SAMPLE_SIGN text inside the\r\nsample SAMPLE_SIGN");
std::smatch m;
std::regex rt("SAMPLE_SIGN([\\S\\s]+)(?=SAMPLE_SIGN)");
std::regex_search(txt, m, rt);

std::cout << m.str(1) << std::endl;
}
```

[C++ Code Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52798026/9534819)